# Solve Gaussian integral over finite interval/limits $\int_{a}^{b}xe^{-m(x-t)^2} dx $

Tags: definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

$\int_{a}^{b}xe^{-m(x-t)^2} dx $

where m and t are constants,

ive tried solving this by ...

$\int_{a}^{b}xe^{-m(x-t)^2} dx $ = $\int_{a}^{b}(x-t)e^{-m(x-t)^2} dx $ + t$\int_{a}^{b}e^{-m(x-t)^2} dx $

substituting **x-t = u** and then

= $\int_{a-t}^{b-t}(u)e^{-m(u)^2} du $ + t$\int_{a-t}^{b-t}e^{-m(u)^2} du $

after that...

as $\int_{a-t}^{b-t}(u)e^{-m(u)^2} du $ = -1/2 $ \int_{a-t}^{b-t}(d/dm)e^{-m(u)^2} du $

not really sure where to go after that or am i on the wrong track???

Comment: Are you sure there's even a closed form for this?

Comment: the result containes the error-function

Comment: @Clarinetist yes.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes but is the way im doing it right so far ? i dont want to use the error function.

Comment: "i dont want to use the error function" Then you *cannot* reach the result. Of course the part $\int ue^{-mu^2}du$ has primitive $-\frac1{2m}e^{-mu^2}$ but the part $\int e^{-mu^2}du$ must involve the error function erf.

Comment: @Did ok, and there is no other way ?

Comment: I thought my first comment was clear enough...